# Hanging a picture on a very light wall

Tags: walls, hanging

How do I hang pictures with sawtooth hangers on a very light (i.e. not compact) wall? Some additional facts:

Plastic hard wall hangers like these do not work:

[image: Hard wall hangers]

I wrecked a frame which I hung on one of these because it fell down.

Ergo, I need something stronger. I tried to drill a hole and fit a plastic anchor, but the anchor wouldn't sit well in the hole because the wall is so light. An attempt with an expansion anchor did not work either.

Do you think I used the wrong kind of expansion anchor? Are there other options? Please advise. The hangers on most of the pictures are of the sawtooth variety. I also have pictures with wires.

Comment: `very light wall` does not mean anything ... please edit your question

Comment: @jsotola I had trouble finding the right word. I now replaced it with "noncompact", but since I posted as a guest the edit has to be reviewed.  If there is a better word, please let me know.

Comment: Show us what kind of "expansion anchor" you used.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I (along with others) rejected your edit; "noncompact" [doesn't mean what I think you think it means](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2y8Sx4B2Sk). A full description of what the wall is made of, and its dimensions (e.g. thickness), would help.

Comment: so you substitute one cryptic description for another .... `noncompact wall` is as useful as `green wall` ... we  still have no idea what you are nailing into

Comment: @jsotola Then please help me write a better question. How do I know what the wall is made of? There isn't a label on it.

Comment: @brhans Unfortunately I don't have them anymore. Searching on Google for "plastic expansion anchor" is enough to see how they look.

Comment: Yeah - no - you see there are the right kind of plastic expansion anchors and there are the wrong kind. I'm going to guess that you've used the ones which are intended for solid masonry walls (because that's a common mistake I've seen over & over) instead of the ones intended for drywall. So, again, show us a pic of what you tried, because a decent *drywall* anchor should hold many 10's of lbs without trouble.

Answer (score 3):

The anchors you chose to use are for a VERY hard wall surface, like concrete or masonry.
The type of wall hangers you would need for a saw tooth hanger could be as simple as a nail driven at an angle or something more suitable off the store shelf.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That looks very promising. I had seen them, but I didn't know that they could support that much weight. My pictures are rather large and the frames are made of metal, but certainly not anywhere near 100lb.